# Using partition and Inherits in one table

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, partitioning

Let's consider I have a four of tables A, B, C, D. 
All of these have 4 exactly the same columns like:

1. last_modified_by
2. last_modified_time
3. active
4. inactive_date

So in order to avoid code duplicacy, I did:

```
    CREATE TABLE X(
        last_modified_by,
        last_modified_time,
        active,
        inactive_date);
```

Now A, B, C and D will be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
     ...,
     ...,
) INHERITS X;
```

Now I want a Partitioning in table A by field **active**. So I will do:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
     ...,
     ...,
) INHERITS X PARTITION BY LIST(active);
```

But this fails with error: **cannot create partitioned table as inheritance child**

So How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use inheritance just to avoid code duplication. You may have unpleasant surprises, e.g. if you want to change the data type of a column for only one table.

Besides, it won't work together with partitioning, because both use the same technology under the hood.

To avoid code duplication, you can use

```
CREATE TABLE b (LIKE a);
```